# Dojo charts create chart with different dimensions

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, dojo, dojox.charting

I created a div with height 240px and add a chart to it. It creates the chart svg with more height of 280px.
My code is:

```
domConstruct.create("div", { id : "chart", style : 
        " width: 400px; height: 240px;  margin: 20px ; " }, 
        dom.byId("header"), "after");
```

And

```
var chart=new Chart("chart");
chart.addPlot("default", {type: Lines});
chart.setTheme(Claro);
chart.addAxis("x");
chart.addAxis("y", { vertical : true});
chart.addSeries("Series A",[1,2,3,4,5,6]);
chart.render();
```

and then the generated html would be like

```
<svg overflow="hidden" width="440" height="280">
```

inside the div id=chart

Because of this, the next chart i created, overlaps this chart.

**Edit** *The important thing here I wanted to achieve is a gap between the charts and not a solution to prevent them from overlapping. Removing the margin would do it but as I said i want some space. Padding also creates the same problem.*

Please see the demo @[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manikantamnk/cLmrqta1/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to take into consideration the margin height also.Your code should like this if you want to fit it into the div

```
domConstruct.create("div", { id : "chart", style : 
            " width: 360px; height: 200px;  margin: 10px ; " }
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. Overlapping just increases with the solution you gave.Might want to reconsider that?